# Problema con OJDBC6 Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse, tomcat

Tengo un proyecto tipo Modulo Maven de Liferay 7, el cual quiero implementar una conexión a Oracle mediante el OJDBC6, tengo mi conexión la cual es la siguiente:

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    if (connection != null) {
        return connection;
    } else {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("miURL", "miUsuario",
                    "miPass");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.out.println(cnfe);
        } catch (SQLException sqe) {
            System.out.println(sqe);
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Obviamente tengo una clase DAO donde utilizo mi conexión, y al momento de utilizar mi DAO en mi controller me marca el siguiente error de la conexión:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

He buscado en muchas páginas e implemente algunas de estas soluciones:

1. Colocar el JAR ojdbc6 en tomcat8/lib/ext
2. Colocar el jar en tomcat8/WebApps/Root/lib/
3. Colocar jar en el path de java
4. Colocar el jar en el repostorio de maven y colocar la dependencia en el pom.xml del proyecto.

Entre otras parecidas... Y hasta ahora nada me ha funcionado, alguien tendra alguna otra solución¿?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He logrado solucionar el problema, tuve que realizar la conexión mediante una Service Builder http://www.javasavvy.com/liferay-7-external-database-servicebuilder-integration/ de esta manera tengo separada mi capa de acceso a datos con la capa del controlador y modelo de datos.

Ademas tuve que agregar el jar OJDBC y ademas un jar para que liferay soporte oracle descargado de aqui https://www.dontesta.it/2016/04/13/liferay-7-ce-how-to-add-support-for-oracle-db/  en TOMCAT_HOME/webApps/ROOT/lib y configure el archivo portal-ext.xml y reinicie el servidor y listo. Espero y les pueda servir de algo.